# How to setup environment for Marlowe Pioneer Program? Error: creating directory '/tmp/nix-shell-1271-0': No space left on device

Tags: marlowe, marlowe-pioneer-program

Im participating in the Marlowe Pioneers program, I setup Nixos with IOHK Binary, then added to Marlowe repository, did cd marlowe-cardano. But when I ran Nix-shell I got an error that I had no space left on device. How much space do I need to run these? Setup is 8GB RAM, 16GB Memory. Are there ways i get better optimise to let Nix-shell work? Thanks for your help.

Comment: All Cardano development environments/tools are extremely space hungry and nix too. Don't bother setting up anything below 100 GB of free space, otherwise you will regret it later, even if it works in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting has nothing to do with the RAM of your environment but with the disk space.

Unfortunately, there is no other way to make Nix work rather than setting up a partition with, at least, 40 GB of free space (to be safe).

This is a screenshot of my `/nix/store` directory, where Nix keeps all its necessary modules:

[image]

You can see it has over 1M files, totalling 33.3 GB.